# translate dynamic text in angular 2 l10n

Tags: angular, l10n.js

i try to translate a dynamic text by this line

```
{{'{{var}}'| translate:lang }}
```

while {{var}} is text that can change in the component.ts
and in my json file i have several options for the dynamic value of "var".

but its dont work. 
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: try {{ var | translate:lang }}

Comment: Your very welcome